# How to distable button backlight when is clicked form code

Tags: windows-phone-7

I must disable (form code) button backlight when I click on it. Default has white backlight.
Anyone know how can I do this?

Comment: Some telephones doesn't have the backlight.

Comment: I don't understand the use case for this, but it's not possible.

Comment: The use case is that I would like to change texture of button without backlight because in my case it doesn't look well

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. There is nothing in the WP7 hardware specification that even dictates the presence of this backlight.

Comment: Also it's not possible to change this backlight in button style in xaml file?